# How to make logic for n input in tictactoe game

Tags: java, android

i made the tictactoe  game using dynamic layout  and applied with logic of  3*3 matrix,if i enter 3 in input so it will make 3*3 matrix, if i will enter 4 in input so it will create 4*4 matrix,i have already make the logic for  3*3 matrix so now i want to make logic for tictactoe which can be applicable for all input.

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
GridLayout gridLayout;

LinearLayout linear;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
Boolean player1 = true;
int turn, n;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.res, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    int i1 = item.getItemId();
    if (i1 == R.id.reset) {
        resetBoard();
        Toast.makeText(this, "game reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (i1 == R.id.newgame) {
        resetgame();
        Toast.makeText(this, "new game", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (i1 == R.id.homebtn) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}

private void resetgame() {
    resetBoard();
    ;
}

private void resetBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

        buttons.get(i).setText("");
        turn = 0;
        player1 = true;
        buttons.get(i).setEnabled(true);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.grid);
    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    linear = findViewById(R.id.linear);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String s = intent.getStringExtra("str");
    n = parseInt(s);
    linear.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linear.setGravity(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    gridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

        Button buttonView = new Button(this);
        buttonView.setId(i);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(n);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(n);
        gridLayout.addView(buttonView);
        buttons.add(buttonView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!((Button) view).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        return;
    }
    if (player1) {
        ((Button) view).setText("X");
    } else {
        ((Button) view).setText("O");
    }
    turn++;
    if (checkforwin(view)) {
        if (player1) {
            player1win();
        } else {
            player2win();
        }
    } else if (turn == n * n) {
        draw();
    } else {
        player1 = !player1;
    }
}

private void player1win() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "player 1 win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

        if (buttons.get(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            buttons.get(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}

private void player2win() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "player 2 win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

        if (buttons.get(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            buttons.get(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}

private void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {

        if (buttons.get(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            buttons.get(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}

private boolean checkforwin(View view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 3).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 6).getText().toString().equals("X") ||
                    buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 3).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 6).getText().toString().equals("O"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    for (int i=0;i<n*n;i=i+3)
    {
        if (buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 1).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 2).getText().toString().equals("X") ||
                buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 1).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 2).getText().toString().equals("O"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 2).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 4).getText().toString().equals("X") ||
                    buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 2).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 4).getText().toString().equals("O"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<n-2; i++)
        {
            if (buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 4).getText().toString().equals("X") && buttons.get(i + 8).getText().toString().equals("X") ||
                    buttons.get(i).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 4).getText().toString().equals("O") && buttons.get(i + 8).getText().toString().equals("O"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

}
}

there is no error for 3*3 matrix,but i want to make dynamic logic which is applicable for all input.

Comment: What are the rules for the tic tac toe in a matrix of size n?

Comment: Your rules in checkforwin() are only applicable for 3*3. You have to check each row, each column and the diagonals whether they have the same flag (x or o).

Comment: yes my rules are only applicable for 3*3 matrix,that's why i'm posting this question because i want to make dynamic logic for  input which is enter by usr, like, if user insert 4 then 4*4 matrix will be created by the dynamic layout and the logic will be also appied automatically. so i want improve my logic dynamically which wil be used for more matrix.

Comment: You could read this:(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79526/tic-tac-toe-getwinner-method-logic-for-a-grid-of-any-size-nxn). There was the same Question.

Comment: yeah i read that question but i think logic was not right, i have already implemented it  and it's not working

Comment: The logik of the question is not right, but the answer should give you some hints how to optimize your code.

Comment: i have already optimized logic using that logic but it's also applicable for only button what i can do if i want to check all button in list.and how it can be possible.i'm clearly asking that how can i made logic for n input like if user entered 4 number then 4*4 matrix also created by dynamic layout but how can we apply logic dynamically.